# Find profile url in Facebook

Tags: java, facebook

Im writing an app for facebook in java.
i have a class named  FacebookClient that i got from facebook.
withe this class i can connect to facebook by using

```
FacebookClient  client = new FacebookClient();
client.login(request, response, "api_key", "sec_key");
```

and get user info with
client.users_getinfo
(For example: `client.users_getinfo(String.class, uidJSON, "first_name , last_name , sex , pic_big , pic_small ", "format=json");`

the problem is that i need the user profile url and i can't get it!!

does anyone know how to get it (the function or the Query )

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Facebook Graph API [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api)

If you make an API call `me` it will return a large JSON containing various information about you, (or a specified user), and one of the entries is `'link'`

Here is a sample call.
`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<the access token>`

and the sample return will look like:

```
{
   "id": "01234567",
   "name": "Kenny Cason",
   "first_name": "Kenny",
   "last_name": "Cason",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/kenny.cason",
   "about": "life only comes once",
   "birthday": "00/11/2222",
   "location": {
      "id": "110184922344060",
      "name": "Washington, District of Columbia"
   },
   ... 
      a bunch more info
   ...
}
```

You can see the link entry which is a link to my facebook profile. let me know if you need more information.